# jQuery data attribute show and hide

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

In my webpage, I have the following menu links:

```
<li class="menu1"><a data-menu="#breakfast">Breakfast</a></li>
<li class="menu2"><a data-menu="#lunch">Lunch</a></li>

<div class="row menu-row" id="breakfast"></div>
<div class="row menu-row" id="lunch"></div>
```

I need to find the div with `#breakfast` and show it. Here's what I've tried:

```
$('.menu-menu li a').click(function () {
    $('.menu-menu li').removeClass('active');
    $('#menu .menu-row').hide(); // hide all
    $(this).attr("data-id").show; //how to find and show the matching div?
});
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: I didn't see #menu in your html code

Comment: @JqueryKing I assumed it was a parent container such as the `ul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you can use `data()` to retrieve data attributes as it's quicker. This will return you a string which you can put in to the selector to get the required element:

```
$('.menu-menu li a').click(function () {
    $('.menu-menu li').removeClass('active');
    $('#menu .menu-row').hide();
    $($(this).data('menu')).show(); 
});
```

Given your HTML it would appear that you want to retrieve the `data-menu` value from the clicked item, not the `data-id`. Also note that you missed the trailing brackets from the `show()` call.

Comment: well that was simple. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: @kmsdev absolute just had time limit of some sort